# How do i align an Element in UWP that i generate through code?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am Programming my first UWP application and i have the problem that i want to generate Buttons from C# code so i can generate them dynamically when needed. In Xaml code the alignment is done through:
`RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"`

(`<Button x:Name="Button1" Content="Button" FontSize="50" FontFamily="Muli" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" Height="250" Width="450" Margin="30" Background="#9cccd2"/>`).

Now when i try it with Code there is the `Button.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;` option. But that does not align my button to the right of the relative Panel, it seemingly changes nothing at all, the Button still appears on the left side.

Is there a way to align my button via Code without having to specify the exact position?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do i align an Element in UWP that i generate through code?

You could call  [`RelativePanel.SetAlignRightWithPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.relativepanel.setalignrightwithpanel?view=winrt-19041) method in the code behind like the following.

```
RelativePanel.SetAlignRightWithPanel(Button1, true);
```

> Now when i try it with Code there is the Button.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right; option. But that does not align my button to the right of the relative Panel

*The HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment properties on UI elements are applied after relationship properties are evaluated and applied. These properties control the placement of the element within the available size for the element, if the desired size is smaller than the available size.* For more please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.RelativePanel?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=winrt-19041#conflicting-relationships).